# How to load libsvm model into Android

Tags: java, android, matlab, libsvm

I have generated a model file from a model trained in MATLAB, and I would like to load this into Android from a mobile device.

The model file looks like this shown for the three first SV's and the params (should be correct):

```
svm_type 0 
kernel_type 2
gamma 3.3636
coef0 0
nr_class 2
total_sv 1106
rho -0.7401
label 0 1
nr_sv 754 352
SV
0 1:8.02710 2:8.90538 3:9.56450 4:10.15383
0 1:7.87334 2:8.71629 3:9.41049 4:9.45693
0 1:8.52795 2:9.19652 3:10.17247 4:10.30913 ...
```

However, when I load this using svm.svm_load_model(), the resulting model is null:

```
FileReader fIn = new FileReader("mymodel.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fIn);
svm_model model = svm.svm_load_model(bufferedReader);
```

I can't seem to find the problem, anyone got an answer?

Thx

**EDIT:** I figured out what the error is. The model file output from MATLAB is apparently not fully compatible with the Android load_model function in the way that the values to keys svm_type and kernel_type has to specified as strings instead of numerals (c_svc instead of 0, rbf instead of 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I figured out what the error is. The model file output from MATLAB is apparently not fully compatible with the Android load_model function in the way that the values to keys svm_type and kernel_type has to specified as strings instead of numerals (c_svc instead of 0, rbf instead of 2).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it because libsvm is written in C/C++. So you can use a wrapper (interfaced by JNI or whatever) to access this "C-based libsvm library" in Android

For example, you can use this wrapper: https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSvm

After you load the program. Go to edit the "AndroidLibSvm/app/src/main/jni/jnilibsvm.cpp" file.
In this file you can load the model file by

```
model=svm_load_model(modelFile);
```

You can also access other libsvm functions as you want

Comment: I appreciate the answer despite the long wait ;) However, I figured out what the problem was. The model file output from MATLAB was not fully compatible with Androids load_model function, the svm_type and kernel_type arguments had to be written in keywords (like c_svc) instead of numerals.